# 302 redirect after CORS preflight

Tags: redirect, laravel-4, cors

I'm running into a problem with a 302 redirect after my CORS preflight has successfully returned a 200 status. I'm currently building an app using Laravel 4.1 and Angular 1.2 as well as my own OAUTH2 server.

The error that Chrome/FF/Safari are sending back to me is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost.api/api/v1/tracks?$filter=id%20eq%20guid%27d7de10ba-e353-455b-a3cb-ced9b4965141%27&`. The request was redirected to '`http://localhost.api/session/invalid`', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

I assume whats causing my issue is the "redirect" thats happening - as my normal CORS requests all work as expected.

My configuration for my Access-Control-Allow-* headers is fairly open right now during testing.

```
  'paths' => array(
      '^/api/' => array(
          'allow_origin'=> array('*'),
          'allow_headers'=> array('Content-Type', 'Authorization'),
          'allow_methods'=> array('POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'),
          'max_age' => 0     
      ),                
      '^/session/' => array(
          'allow_origin'=> array('*'),
          'allow_headers'=> array('Content-Type', 'Authorization'),
          'allow_methods'=> array('GET', 'OPTIONS'),               
          'max_age' => 0                                                        
      )
```

The redirect in question is in a pre-filter thats checking the validity of an OAUTH2 access token

```
public function filter($route, $request, $data = null)                       
{                                                                            
    //  Get the authorization header or fail                                 
    if ($authorization = Request::header('Authorization', false)) {          
        list($type, $token) = explode(' ', $authorization);                  
        if (is_null($auth = OAuth2::token($token)->first())) {               
            return Redirect::to('session/invalid');                                                              
        }                                                                    
        $tokenExpiryDate = Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($auth->access_token_expires);

        //  If we don't have a Bearer authentication header                  
        //  or if the token has expired.  Then redirect to an                
        //  expired session route                                            
        if (   'bearer' != strtolower($type)                                 
            || Carbon::now()->gt($tokenExpiryDate)                           
        ) {                                                                  
            return Redirect::route(                                          
                'expiredSession',                                            
                array('expiry' => $tokenExpiryDate->timestamp)               
            );                                                               
        }                                                                    
    } else {                                                                 
        //  The authentication header is invalid, redirect to let the user know.
        return Redirect::to('session/invalid');                              
    }                                                                        
}
```

All these requests worked when I tried debugging using POSTMAN, but after my research I've basically found that extensions don't necessarily have to play by the same rules.  As well as I noticed my requests using POSTMAN never send any preflight OPTIONS requests when I initiate a simple GET, POST, etc..

Here are the headers of both an OPTIONS request as well as a GET request to follow it that is returning my error

### OPTIONS Request

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80 
Request URL:http://localhost.api/api/v1/tracks?$filter=id%20eq%20guid%27d7de10ba-e353-455b-a3cb-ced9b4965141%27&
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:vegas.ine.com
Origin:http://localhost.angular
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost.angular/admin/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost.angular
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 01 May 2014 16:22:19 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IktOZjlTM1ZVNUx0TEhoaTczY3dQcDBKRWlvbnppbDA3QTdqSENJdTc2R1U9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJEZ2ltXC9mNm1Qa20rV3BVRlNHTXgySGtUeVlpNjNZcGFudDFBWDJJekl1MEVNVlhSRE5WWk5YZDNxUkZuU0VEVytcL3NLNlVBXC9hZWtJQzdHU2FqVWtMdz09IiwibWFjIjoiYTYxYjEwNjlmYmI2MjMwNmE4MzlkYjIwNGZlNzA4Y2ViZGVkZmU1MTQzMzc5NmU2YzI2ZGExNzYxY2U5ZjdiMCJ9; expires=Thu, 01-May-2014 18:22:19 GMT; path=/; httponly
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.24
```

### GET Request

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://localhost.api/api/v1/tracks?$filter=id%20eq%20guid%27d7de10ba-e353-455b-a3cb-ced9b4965141%27&
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Bearer 6Ss4XPrPM5jQD7Es0dz7TPRQ76hGA69vT9K94pst
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:vegas.ine.com
Origin:http://localhost.angular
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost.angular/admin/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost.angular
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 01 May 2014 16:22:19 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Location:http://localhost.api/session/invalid
Server:Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InlnREVPcUJTcyswMnRLanFDSlZ6QWFBVXZWMGdMNVNLYWxNTHRJVUlkalk9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ4aXN5U0dcL1NYeGQrcUVzWFhYV3o2MWhcL25hQTlhcVUxbWxkN2R6SG9KZDNKaGNLTkRQY2FyTitpVHNGZzYxVVRtZUhoZGZRWE9GWjZRaDd1VVwvZUZuUT09IiwibWFjIjoiY2EzZTViZGIzZmVlMDcwZjdhMzBjOWQxYTgwZWNlYTJiMDk3ODdlZTk3NTYxMDNmM2YyODJjOGIxMzBmMmJlMiJ9; expires=Thu, 01-May-2014 18:22:20 GMT; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Authorization
X-Clockwork-Id:1398961340.2239.1349476325
X-Clockwork-Version:1.5
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.24
```

Comment: The error message makes it pretty clear: redirects are not allowed for preflighted requests. The ways to work around this are to either avoid the redirect, or remove the need to issue a preflight request. Are either of these an option for you?

Comment: not really :/  are there other approaches to get around this problem?

Comment: One idea is to return a custom error code to the client, and have the client manually redirect to 'session/invalid' in the JavaScript code. Its not ideal, but it may provide a workaround.

Comment: Same problem here... Any news?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this and it worked fine for me

```
//pattern to allow origins
$allowedOriginPattern = /** YOUR PATTERNS **/;
$allowedOrigin = "";
if (preg_match($allowedOriginPattern, $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    $allowedOrigin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
}

/**
 * set http content type
 */
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $allowedOrigin);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
```

I have added this code in laravel index.php

Here is the reference for CORS
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

Answer (score 0):

Spent an hour and this trying to redirect to a subdomain

Instead just used javascript after a successful response

`window.location.href = resp.data.redirect`