# Why does CORS specification not allow redirects?

Tags: http, redirect, cors, w3c

The [W3C CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-cors-20140116/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) clearly states in *Step 2*:

> **If the response has an HTTP status code of 301, 302, 303, 307, or 308**
>
> ```
>  Apply the cache and network error steps.
> ```

I think that this measure has been added to mitigate security risks. However, I am unable to find a source detailing what exactly the security ramifications of allowing redirects will be.

---

Questions about how to circumvent this issue have been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412037/302-redirect-after-cors-preflight). I am looking for an explanation of why was this clause included in the specification in the first place, like the following questions:

[CORS - What is the motivation behind introducing preflight requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381105/cors-what-is-the-motivation-behind-introducing-preflight-requests)

[Why does a cross-origin HEAD request need a preflight check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107694/why-does-a-cross-origin-head-request-need-a-preflight-check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WHATWG mailing list](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2014-June/297125.html):

> Mostly because with preflight fetches everything gets more
>   complicated. We did leave the door open to potentially allow this at
>   some point, provided we figure out a sane protocol, but left it out
>   initially for simplicity.